# Generate D3js chart within NodeJS console application

Tags: node.js, d3.js

I am looking for some assistance on generating a D3js chart within a NodeJS console application and saving the chart to disk as a PNG or JPG.

My use case involves an automated task that runs every fortnight and loops through a list of results, generating an email notification to customers. Within that email, I want to include various charts generated using D3js. To embed the D3js charts into our customer emails, we need to save the D3js chart to disk/stream as a PNG/JPG to upload the image to our SMTP provider. The charts and data are dynamic and unique to each customer, so the chart needs to be generated immediately before the email is sent to the customer.

I've seen SaaS offerings to generate D3js charts via API, but that's been ruled out by management (:shrug:).

The non-SaaS D3js examples I've found online are centred around embedding charts into web pages. That's not what we're looking to do.

I'm stuck on where to get started, which is why there are no code examples in this post. Any assistance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

d3.js manipulates the HTML DOM. Thus, it requires the DOM JavaScript API which exists in the browser.

If you want to use d3.js in Node.js, you can use libraries like [`jsdom`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsdom) to **emulate the DOM** and its API.

You may then use the [`sharp`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sharp) package to convert the SVG to a PNG or any image file.

```
// use jsdom to emulate the browser DOM
const jsdom = require('jsdom');
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;

// for saving the SVG image to disk
const fs = require('fs');
// for converting SVG to an image
const sharp = require('sharp');

/** renders a D3.js generated SVG DOM into an image file */
const renderD3ImageFile = async (data) => {
  /************************************************/
  /************** Emulating the DOM ***************/
  /************************************************/

  // emulate the DOM structure
  const dom = new JSDOM('<!DOCTYPE html><body><svg id="bar-chart"></svg></body></html>')
  // get the SVG container element
  const svgElement = dom.window.document.getElementById("bar-chart");

  /************************************************/
  /****************** D3 Drawing ******************/
  /************************************************/

  /* Import the d3 library
  If your node app is of 'module' type, you can simply use the syntax "import * as d3 from 'd3'"
  Earlier versions of d3 can be loaded using commonJs.
  */
  const d3 = await import('d3');

  // select the SVG element using D3.js
  const svg = d3.select(svgElement)
    // not sure if this is necessary
    .attr('xmlns', "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg");

  const svgWidth = 1080;
  const svgHeight = 300;

  /* Sizing the svg image
  Since our DOM is emulated, we cannot enquire any sizing information from it.
  We can either size the SVG by (1) providing fixed height/width values or (2) by using the viewBox attribute.

  The following code uses the viewBox attributes
   */
  svg.attr('width', `${svgWidth}px`)
    .attr('height', `${svgHeight}px`);

  // any kind of D3.js magic

  const x = d3.scaleLinear([0, 100], [0, svgWidth]);
  const coreGroup = svg.append('g').attr('class', 'core-group');
  const barHeight = 50;
  const barTopMargin = 10;
  const someRandomBars = coreGroup.selectAll('g.bar')
    .data([10, 75, 100, 24, 55])
    .enter()
    .append('g')
    .attr('class', 'bar')
    .attr('transform', (d,i) => `translate(0 ${i * (barHeight + barTopMargin)})`);
  someRandomBars.append('rect')
    .attr('x', 0).attr('y', 0)
    .attr('width', (d) => {
      return x(d) + 'px';
    })
    .attr('height', `${barHeight}px`)
    // all styling has to be done inline
    .attr('fill', 'purple');

  // the html of the element is our SVG image
  const svgAsText = svgElement.outerHTML;

  // save as SVG (for debugging)
  fs.writeFileSync('output.svg', svgAsText);

  // save as raster image file
  const svgImageBuffer = Buffer.from(svgAsText);
  await sharp(svgImageBuffer)
    .png()
    .toFile("output.png");
};

// trigger the render promise
renderD3ImageFile()
  .then(() => console.log('picture rendered!'))
  .catch(error => console.error(error));
```

This code creates a simple bar chart PNG image:

[image]

### Common Challenges & Thoughts

#### Loading d3.js in Node.js

The recent version of d3.js is an ES module. So unless your Node.js app is to `"type": "module"` you have to load it through the `import('d3')` promise.
Many examples are using CommonJS with earlier versions of d3.

#### Sizing the image & elements

There are two approaches to sizing your SVG drawing:

1. Use static `width` and `height` attributes (like in the example above).
2. Use the `viewBox` with `preserveAspectRatio` attributes. I like using this because it provides a bit more flexibility in future placement of the image.

It is important to know that the DOM is emulated only. I.e. the DOM functions to enquire about size (`getBBox()`) do not exist.

#### Rendering for HTML vs Image

When rendering SVG for HTML, we can (and should) make use of CSS styles. When rendering SVG in Node.js we have to deploy all styles inline.
This might be an issue when trying to share your d3.js code between client and server-side.